# Cannot handle button tap in ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, win-universal-app

I have a `ListView` with custom `ItemContainer` and `ItemTemplate`. `ItemTemplate` contains, among other controls, a button. Whenever I click or tap a button `ListView` a whole item is selected, in contrast to the expected button click or tap event to be fired. I've noticed that the only time the button is clickable is when I position mouse cursor at the top border of the button (whichi is also the only time I am getting the default mouse over effect).

Here is the XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="SalesOrdersListViewStyle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>-->
                <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,6"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <ListViewItemPresenter 
                                Foreground="{StaticResource HighlightPressedBrush}" 
                                CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" 
                                ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                CheckMode="Inline" 
                                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                                CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" 
                                DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                                DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" 
                                DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
                                DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" 
                                FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}" 
                                FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" 
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                PointerOverForeground="{StaticResource HighlightPressedBrush}" 
                                PressedBackground="{ThemeResource HighlightAlternativePressedBrush}" 
                                PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
                                PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource HighlightPointerOverBrush}" 
                                ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" 
                                SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ControlBackgroundDarkBrush}" 
                                SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True" 
                                SelectedForeground="#FFFFFFFF" 
                                SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource HighlightAlternativePointerOverBrush}" 
                                SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource HighlightPressedBrush}" 
                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock 
                        x:Uid="SalesOrderNumber" 
                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <TextBlock 
                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                        Text="{Binding Number}" />

                    <!-- TEST BUTTON THAT CANNOT BE TAPPED -->
                    <Button 
                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="3"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Background="Red"
                        IsHitTestVisible="True" 
                        Content="TEST" />

                    <TextBlock 
                        x:Uid="DeliveryMode" 
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <TextBlock 
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                        Text="{Binding DeliveryMode}" /
                    <TextBlock 
                        x:Uid="ShippingDate" 
                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <TextBlock 
                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                        Text="{Binding ShippingDate}" />
                    <TextBlock 
                        x:Uid="ProjectNumber" 
                        Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <TextBlock 
                        Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                        Text="{Binding ProjectNumber}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How do I make the button click or tap event to fire instead of selecting an item?

Note: I just commented out the entire `<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">` and the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in you TextBlocks with `Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"`. Set `ColumSpan` to 1 and it will work.

Comment: Dear mother of god, why did I not see this? And why are there `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` in the first place? Thanks RavingDev!

Answer (score 0):

I am a total newbie but couldn't you just add a Button click event?

```
<Button 
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="3"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Background="Red"
    IsHitTestVisible="True"
    Click"btn_Click"
    Content="TEST" />
```

And in the code:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

I hope I don't talk bullsh*t here but I don't see your click event anywhere.

Comment: Jasper, thanks for a reply. No, the problem is that even if did add a `Click` event, it wouldn't be fired, because the click is handled as `ListView` item selection. The reason why I do not have the `Click` event at all is because I am using MVVM, and am therefore handling the click or tap by specifying a Command. But the problem is somewhere in the UI tree view and `IsHitTestVisible` property, not in the actual event handler.